# How to convert a decimal into binary and vice versa

Tags: unix, binary, decimal, solaris-10

how to convert Decimal to binary and viceversa

i am working on solaris10 platform

can anybody help me with a command

```
Decimal to Binary
4000000002-100000000000000000000000000010

Binary to decimal
100000000000000000000000000010-4000000002
```

Comment: Any particular programming language?

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of the `bc` command for this.

For Decimal to binary, set `obase` to `2`

```
echo 'obase=2;4000000002' | bc
```

For Binary to Decimal, set `ibase` to `2`

```
echo 'ibase=2;100000000000000000000000000010' | bc
```

Comment: hi i have 2 crores record like this but the above command takes lot of time. any other command works faster than this

Comment: great answer - Thanks!